# Arrow functions with async and await in react native

Tags: javascript, async-await, react-native

I am trying to save data in `AsyncStorage` in `react-native`. I want to save it asynchronous so using `async` and `await` keyword.

```
  async onPositiveClickListener = () => {
    // user has completed product tour_end
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem("@ProductTour:key", "true");
      const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
      navigate("DashboardScreen");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

I am getting an error while saving program

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected ( (40:32)
  38 |   };
  39 | 
> 40 |   async onPositiveClickListener = () => {
     |                                 ^
  41 |     // save user has completed product tour_end
  42 |     try {
  43 |       await AsyncStorage.setItem("@ProductTour:key", "true");
Hide Stack Trace
SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected ( (40:32)
  38 |   };
  39 | 
> 40 |   async onPositiveClickListener = () => {
     |                                 ^
  41 |     // save user has completed product tour_end
  42 |     try {
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Async named arrow function should be declared like

```
const onPositiveClickListener = async () => {
    // user has completed product tour_end
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem("@ProductTour:key", "true");
      const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
      navigate("DashboardScreen");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

Comment: AsyncStorage takes three arguments, key and value which are both string , along with that a callback function, so no you can only set string with AsyncStorage. What you can do is convert your other datatype to a string with `JSON.stringify(obj)`  and parse it after retreving, that way you can save any other data type