# Async Function not recognize in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile, mobile-application

I know this is common to asks but I'm facing a weird problem. In my react native app I just want to call a function within the file but it seems it returns an error, under my `functionOne` after this will returns `functionTwo` but it gives me an error. Need help

```
[ReferenceError: Can't find variable: functionTwo]
```

Updated: The `functionOne` indicates to reset PinCode and then it Logout the googleSignIn since it has `functionTwo();` inside `functionOne` and the `functionTwo` indicates logout of googleSignIn

I put those functions inside `<AuthContext.Provider>` because I want to reuse or called the function everywhere on screens just like a global function/variable

Updated : **AuthProvider.js**

```
return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        user,
        setUser,
        functionOne: async () => {
          try {
            await deleteUserPinCode();
            await resetPinCodeInternalStates();
            functionTwo();   //this returns an error --------------------------------
          } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
            console.log("Please contact administrator");
          }
        },

        functionTwo: async () => {
          try {
            GoogleSignin.configure({});
            await GoogleSignin.revokeAccess();
            await GoogleSignin.signOut();
            setUser({ user: null });
            AsyncStorage.setItem('userPrivilege', '');
            await auth().signOut();
            console.log("sa try");
          } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
            console.log("Please contact administrator");
          }
        },
      }
      } >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider >
  );
```

Updated this is what I've tried latest but it returns me also the error

`Can't find  variable:functionOne`

[image]

```
  functionOne = async (e) => {
    try {
      await deleteUserPinCode();
      await resetPinCodeInternalStates();
      functionTwo();
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      console.log("Please contact administrator");
    }
  };
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        user,
        setUser,
        functionOne: this.functionOne,
        
        functionTwo: async () => {
          try {
            GoogleSignin.configure({});
            await GoogleSignin.revokeAccess();
            await GoogleSignin.signOut();
            setUser({ user: null });
            AsyncStorage.setItem('userPrivilege', '');
            await auth().signOut();
            console.log("sa try");
          } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
            console.log("Please contact administrator");
          }
        },
      }
      } >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider >
  );
```

Comment: can you add more info on how/where u using the functionOne and functionTwo ?

Comment: @Thinker I've added more info in my updated above

Comment: if the function are stored in object, then try calling it by `this.functionTwo()`

Comment: @Thinker I tried that before but it is not an object

Comment: @Thinker I'm sorry, my info is lack, the function that I've been using are inside `<AuthContext.Provider>`  I put those functions because I want to reuse or called the function everywhere in screens just like global function , but yet it didn't fixed my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
class AppProvider extends React.Component {
  
  const functionOne = async (e) => {
    try {
      ....
    } catch (e) {
      ....
    }
  };
  
  const functionTwo = async (e) => {
    try {
      ....
    } catch (e) {
      ....
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <AppContext.Provider
        value={{
          ....
          functionOne: this.functionOne,
          functionTwo: this.functionTwo,
        }}
      >
     {children}
     </AppContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
export default AppProvider;
```

Comment: I tried but I think it didn't work I've added image above on how I've implemented your code , did I missed something? I should also update the functionTwo outside the return but In the first place the functionOne not been Identified

Comment: @CarlJade have you tried removing `this` from `this.functionOne` ?

Comment: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8Xbp.png) Yes I just tried it now but the error is the same , I think this is the correct answer but I think it just a little changes to fix it, did I missed something? should I add `render(){}` ??

Comment: @CarlJade try different way of declaring function as I have updated answer please check.. check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/43718149/1283345 and https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/async+await+arrow+function

Comment: Thanks, it works now I just used the link that you've provided on declaring the function

Answer (score 0):

You can change the way you declare your functions to

```
async function functionOne(){}
```

and the same for the other one. At least that works for me.

Comment: I tried that format before but it seems it's not working [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nnZ8.png) since my functions are inside  `<AuthContext.Provider>`

Comment: Oh you are right! - why not put them then outside of that container? And hand it over to the same? See the next answer :)